# Strip text from <td> and <a href> in the same <tr>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to scrape some data and I'm running into the following problem:

```
for tr in soup.select("tr[class^='rg']"):
    row = [ td.text.strip() for td in tr('td')[1:-1] ]
    if row:
        print(','.join(row))
```

I've selected the classes I want data from, but a couple of the fields in each row are a's nested under the td's and in one case there's tooltip text I'd like to grab. Ideally I'd use the same loop here to extract the other text as well.

```
<tr class="rgRow">
    <td><a href="webpage.aspx?>Text</a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" tooltip="Tooltip text"><img border="0" src="images/note.png"/></a>
    </td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some More Text</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
row = [ td.text.strip() for td in tr('td')[1:-1] ]
```

with

```
row = [td.text.strip() or td.a['tooltip'] for td in tr('td')[1:-1]]
```

To get text of `td` node or `@tooltip` from `a` child node

Comment: I appreciate that suggestion. That allows me to get the tooltip.

The open bit is how to grab the text of the anchor inside the td as well.

Comment: You mean from this anchor `<td><a href="webpage.aspx?>Text</a></td>`?

Comment: Yes, that's the one from the example. I'd like to extract that, the tooltip and the two td texts in that same loop. I have tried a few different things, including reading the documentation, but I feel like I'm chaining a few ideas together.

Comment: Try to remove the slice `[1:-1]` which force to ignore the first and last `td` nodes. My code should allow you to get all required data... Maybe your real HTML code sample is slightly different comparing with provided one?

Comment: Bingo. Thank you Andersson. Much appreciated. General Python skills were there challenge here, not my understanding. Much appreciated.